# Histogram Feature Vector

Tags: java, image-processing, histogram

I have made this method which gets me the values of red, green and blue and stores them in a temp int, and then adds that int to the array. l want to combine these values without merging them, but am not sure how?

```
public static double[] GetHistogram (BufferedImage img) {
    double[] myHistogram = new double [256];

    int Temp = 0;
    int Temp1 = 0;
    int Temp2 = 0;

     for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y += 1)
     {
         for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x += 1)
         {
              int clr =  img.getRGB(x,y); 

              int  red   = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
              int  green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
              int  blue  =  clr & 0x000000ff;

             Temp = 0;
             Temp1 = 0;
             Temp2 = 0; 

            Temp += red;
            Temp1 += green;
            Temp2 += blue;

             Temp = (int) Temp;
             myHistogram[Temp]++;
             myHistogram[Temp1]++;
             myHistogram[Temp2]++;
         }

     }
     return myHistogram;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *combine these values without merging them*?

Comment: So im using this method to compare an image with a file of other images and return the closest based on the values of red, then green, then blue. I want to combine them in such a way that l can retain the information specific to each histogram rather than merging them as l have done.

Comment: Then use three arrays - I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I mean combine them in some way without taking their average.  Is there a way l can do this by having a longer histogram/feature vector?

Comment: your code looks really weird. a lot of things don't make any sense. I think you should focus on programming basics befor you continue. you cast an int to int which makes no sense but you only do it for one of three similar variables... you assign zero to variables, then add a positive number instead of just assinging this number directly... 
I suggest you go through every line of code and ask yourself why am I doing this?